# Making a PHP/MySQL Search Engine

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

In a site I'm making, I need a search engine to find songs for people to listen to. I have it working to the point that it can get info from the database and display them on the page. The problem comes when there are two songs with the same name. I have a system so the results will go to separate links, but when I search them they display the same image even though there is two separate sources for them. It also will make extra results for some reason. Here's my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    mysql_connect('********', '********', '********');
    mysql_select_db('********');
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ******** WHERE title LIKE '$q'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
} else {
    echo "
<span style='font-family: Helvetica, Arial;font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px;'>Search</span>
<form action='http://www.example.com/search' method='get'>
<input placeholder='Search for music' type='text' name='q' style='font-weight:bold;padding:5px;width:300px;border-top-left-radius: 4px;border-top-right-radius: 10px;border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;border: 3px solid gray;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;' />
</form>
    ";
}
if ($numrows != 0) {
    $index = 0;
    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $results[$index] = $row;
        $index++;
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $url = "http://www.example.com?id=" . $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $arturl = $row['art_url'];
            if ($_GET['q'] != "") {
                echo "
                    <a href='$url'>
                    <table>
                    <tr style='text-align:left;'>
                    <td><img src='$arturl' style='width:100px;height:100px;'></td>
                    <td>
                    <span class='songTitle'>$title</span>
                    <br/>
                    <span class='songArtist'>By: Unknown</span>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </a>
                    <br />              
                ";
            }
        }   
    }
} else {
    if ($_GET['q'] != "") {
        echo "
<span style='font-family: Helvetica, Arial;font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px;'>Search</span>
<form action='********' method='get'>
<input placeholder='Search for music' type='text' name='q' style='font-weight:bold;padding:5px;width:300px;border-top-left-radius: 4px;border-top-right-radius: 10px;border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;border: 3px solid gray;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;' />
</form>
        ";
        echo "<br />No results where found.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You definitely won't have a very good search engine if you're using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Okay, I'll read that. But for now I need this to work before I completely change the site!

Comment: I don't think you understand the consequences of using the code you have.

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10 times a day.

Comment: I am currently looking into MySQLi right now guys! I just need a solution for now.

Comment: @Dagon They probably won't see it if they actually appreciated what the message says.

Comment: @Gordan: "*Before I completely change the site*" - inserting the letter `i` into each `mysql_` function call (which is almost all that is *necessary* to switch to MySQLi) is hardly a massive deal.  One should, of course, take the opportunity to parameterise statements too - but that's another matter.

Comment: Really?! Wow. I guess I'll try that then. And what do you mean by "parameterise statements"? (Sorry I'm some-what new to MySQL)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))Try `$result['title']` instead of `$row['title']`;. Same goes to `$url` and `$arturl`

This should work.

```
if ($numrows != 0) {
    $index = 0;
    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $url = "http://www.example.com?id=" . $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $arturl = $row['art_url'];
            if ($_GET['q'] != "") {
                echo "
                    <a href='$url'>
                    <table>
                    <tr style='text-align:left;'>
                    <td><img src='$arturl' style='width:100px;height:100px;'></td>
                    <td>
                    <span class='songTitle'>$title</span>
                    <br/>
                    <span class='songArtist'>By: Unknown</span>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </a>
                    <br />              
                ";
            }
    }           
    }
```

Comment: It's displaying the info just fine. The problem is, it's making duplicates.

Comment: i think you should use either 'while' or 'foreach'. Not both. There is no need of that while loop.

Comment: Is it bad that I use both? What is the reason? Also, how do I change that `foreach` loop to a `while` loop?

Comment: Okay. I did what you said, removed the `while` loop and change `$row[''];` to `$result[''];`. Now it's just displaying one result. There is supposed to be two.

Comment: that is because of your index++. Remove it.

Comment: Also echo $numrows and make sure there are 2 results.

Comment: WHOA! That didn't work!! It was displaying infinite results.. WTF?

Comment: http://www.dione.site11.com/search/?q=Song+title Okay, maybe not INFINITE results but a lot of them.

Comment: just echo $numrows and tell me what you are getting. That will match your result.

Comment: Don't know what the heck is goin' on there. It's not displaying the images at all now. It's making to of each of those "results". AND it's giving them weird names. Dangit. Okay I'll echo $numrows out...

Comment: try print_r($row) and see the result;

Comment: Array ( [0] => null [song_url] => null [1] => 5 [id] => 5 [2] => Song title [title] => Song title [3] => http://www.dione.site11.com/create/uploads/albumart_l9XwbY8E4SKqu7GR6NLreaQmnUhcIH3OxA1JZPvV_gun-100x100.jpg [art_url] => http://www.dione.site11.com/create/uploads/albumart_l9XwbY8E4SKqu7GR6NLreaQmnUhcIH3OxA1JZPvV_gun-100x100.jpg )

Comment: there seems to be only one result when you tried print_r($row)

Comment: Okay. So after all of this I notice that the images are the same in the DB. I'm so stupid. I'm gonna change the image and try it.

Comment: http://www.dione.site11.com/search/?q=Song+title Okay It's working perfectly. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

your codes seem right. However, to clarify, try to echo $arturl and see if it is getting the right source name. And also check the value in the database. Last thing is try to check whether the source image is in the correct folder. Try and give the feedback.

Comment: You can see what I'm talking about here: http://www.dione.site11.com/search/?q=Song+title

Comment: i have seen it. the first one is id=5, but the second and third id=8. the id is same. better check that one. the id should not be the same. try to remove foreach, and just use while loop and see what is going on. while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { echo $row['id']. " " . $row['titlle'] . " " .$row['art_url']; }

Comment: Check it out now. I did what @Phphelp said to do. Still having problems though. (Now it's the opposite. There is only one result.)

Comment: try the current post by Phphelp, I can't post a code here but i will go for phphelp codes.

Comment: hey try this 
if ($numrows != 0) {
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo $row['id']. " " . $row['titlle'] . " " .$row['art_url'];
}
}


try this simple code first. remove those indexes,array,foreach. just use while loop.

Comment: give it a try and see what happen.